# Can't get title of latest post

Tags: plugins, get-the-title

I've just started learning PHP/Wordpress yesterday - here is one of my first plugins. Unfortunately, it's not working like it's supposed to - the title doesn't display. What's wrong with my code?

```
function show_title_on_dashboard() {

    $newest_post_id = $post[0]->ID;

    $title = $newest_post_id->post_title;

    echo "Latest Post: $title";
}

add_action("admin_notices", "show_title_on_dashboard");
```

Comment: There is no variable declared $post at that moment, and even if you have access to (and using) the global $post, it's not an array. You need to run a loop to fetch the latest post first and then display the data here. Read more about the loop - http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 3):

You're getting there! Couple of issues - you need to actually *grab* the latest posts before you can work on them. And `post_title` is not a property of the ID, but the object itself:

```
if ( $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=1' ) ) {
    $title = $posts[0]->post_title;
    // carry on sir
}
```

**Note:** Ensure you have `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )` in your `wp-config.php` when developing on WordPress - it will help **immensely** with debugging!

Comment: Fantastic! My first program is now functional - much obliged for the help. Quick ? - why use an if statement to declare the $posts variable? Does it help prevent an error from occurring?

Comment: Absolutely - if `get_posts()` fails (for whatever reason), trying to access `$posts[0]` would throw an "undefined index" notice.